# iOS Local Notifications/Silent Push Notifications to wake up TERMINATED app & run code

Tags: ios, notifications, push, uilocalnotification

I'm a bit confused at all the options or lack of options to wake up a completely terminated app to fetch a user's location and make a url request - without the user interacting with the device.

I want my app to be able to periodically (every 24 hours or so) check the user's location and query the server if the user's location should cause them to be notified.

There seem to be two options that may be able to achieve this, one is a `UILocalNotification` and the other is a silent push notification.

The question is, if my app is completely terminated, can a notification from either or both of these cause the app (without the user doing anything) to open in the background and achieve these tasks?

If so, can someone point me in the right direction as to what code is executed upon receiving one of these notifications and I stress, without user's interaction?

There is also background app refresh but this seems to require the app to be running in the background and won't work when the app is terminated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean terminated by the system or terminated by the user from the app switcher?

Comment: Terminated via the app switcher.

Comment: I beleive only voip apps can recover from that.

Comment: Doesn't foursquare have similar functionality?

Comment: What about apps like Happn which can track your location in the background even if the app has been force closed by the user?